# How and when are idols cleaned in temples?

Tags: temple, customs, idols

I saw many time idols are getting cleaned by priests.

My question are:

- What is used to cleanup the idols?
- Just water or something else?
- Is there any timing for cleaning?

Comment: Are you asking about Abhishekams? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhisheka

Comment: water and tamarind pulp are used for cleaning idols. typically done on Ekadasi day.